# Insert image in slickgrid column cells and make it clickable

Tags: slickgrid

I am trying to insert an image in  a column called "Image" which should contain only the image. I am fetching the image Dictionary.png from Images folder and have assigned the path in column during initialization of the column.First, the image is not displayed in column cells but place holder is visible. What is that i am missing out in code? And  secondly, how to make the image clickable, so that on click of the image, an alert box should appear. Please find the code i have written to insert image and display alert box on click. The path given in   src is correct. It will be helpful if someone can resolve this issue.

```
columns = [{ id:"Image" name:"Image", field: "image",formatter: function(args) {return "<img id='Image' src ='../../Images/Bookimage.png'></img>" } }];

$('#Image').on('click', function () {
alert("It Works");
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I've written an example at jsFiddle:
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ryurt5qt/)

```js
var imageFormatter = function(){
    return "<img class='clickableImage' src='http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/images/tick.png' />";
};

var grid;
  var data = [];
  var columns = [
      {id: "imageCol", name: "Image", field: "somefield", sortable: false, width: 80, minWidth: 20, maxWidth: 80, formatter: imageFormatter}
  ];

var options = {
    editable: false,
    enableAddRow: false,
    enableCellNavigation: false,
    enableColumnReorder: false
  };

  $(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        data.push({somefield:true});
    }

    grid = new Slick.Grid("#grid", data, columns, options);
  });

$("#grid").on("click", "img.clickableImage", function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

```css
img.clickableImage{
   cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<div id="grid" style="height: 300px;"></div>

<link href="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/examples.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js"></script>
```

There were few issues on your code:

First, you cannot put an id on your image tag in the formatter, id should be unique for all html tags in your body!

Second, you should attach the click event handler to the div that is the element that contains the grid, and allow bubbling to it so it will be attached to all future elements inside that html.

Last, an empty place holder in the image normally means that the image in not were you referenced to. Double check your src...